# Why do some clojure functions have dots at the end or beginning of their names?

Tags: clojure

`(.parse (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "yyyy-MM-dd") date)`

Why does `java.text.SimpleDateFormat.` end in a dot?
Why does `.parse` start with a dot?

Comment: Those are for Java interop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are to distinguish functions from Java methods.

```clj
(.parse (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "yyyy-MM-dd") date)
```

Is the same as:

```clj
(.parse (new java.text.SimpleDateFormat "yyyy-MM-dd") date)
```

Which is the same as the following Java code:

```java
(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")).parse(date)
```

You can of course do a lot more so if you want to use a library in your Clojure code you might want to look the [Clojure's Java interop pages](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop).